# Не работает Ajax подгрузка

Tags: ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
url: '/your-script.php?parametr=1',
cache: false,
beforeSend: function() {
$("#getContent").html('Подождите, загружается контент');
},
success: function(html){
$("#getContent").html(html);
}
});
});
</script>
                                <a href="#" id="getContent">Загрузить контент</a>
<div id="divContent"></div>
```

а в консоли мне пишет следующее Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Comment: jquery видимо не подключили

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался, функция $ была занята, вместо $ надо было поставить jQuery